# Replacing different spellings for same word in R

Tags: r

my data has a column of cities where a same city has been written differently. For example the city 'Bangalore' (correct spelling) has been spelled as 'bangalore','bengaluru','banglore' etc. I want to make all these different spelling into one correct spelling. Till now I have been doing it manually searching for the different spellings and replacing it with the correct.

Can anyone help me to get this process done faster and less of manual work using R?

Thank You

Comment: Using a variety of passes might help you. Even something as simple as removing vowels can be helpful for grouping: `gsub("[aeiouy]", "", c("bangalore", "bengaluru", "banglore"))` for instance gives `"bnglr"` for all 3 variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below an example using `stringdist` which can calculate similarity between strings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringdist)
```

Generate some sample data:

```
cities <- data.frame(city = c('bangalore','bengaluru','banglore',
  'bangalore', 'bangalore', 'bangalore', 'new york', 'newyork', 
  'nyork', 'new york', 'new york'))
```

Determine unique values and calculate how often these occur (the most frequent one will probably be the correct one)

```
dta <- cities %>% group_by(city) %>% count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% mutate(i = row_number())
```

For each combination of city names calculate a simularity, put most similar ones on top

```
pairs <- expand.grid(x = seq_len(nrow(dta)), y = seq_len(nrow(dta))) %>% 
  # Only need to compare i to  all records j, with j > i 
  filter(y > x) %>%
  left_join(dta, by = c(x = 'i')) %>% rename(cityx = city, nx = n) %>%
  left_join(dta, by = c(y = 'i')) %>% rename(cityy = city, ny = n) %>%
  mutate(similarity = stringsim(cityx, cityy, method = "jw")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(similarity))
```

You can then investigate top records:

```
> pairs
#    x y     cityx nx     cityy ny similarity
# 1  1 2 bangalore  4  banglore  1  0.9629630
# 2  4 5  new york  3   newyork  1  0.9583333
# 3  5 6   newyork  1     nyork  1  0.9047619
# 4  4 6  new york  3     nyork  1  0.8750000
# 5  2 3  banglore  1 bengaluru  1  0.7222222
# 6  1 3 bangalore  4 bengaluru  1  0.6944444
# 7  2 6  banglore  1     nyork  1  0.6583333
# 8  2 5  banglore  1   newyork  1  0.6011905
# 9  1 5 bangalore  4   newyork  1  0.5873016
# 10 2 4  banglore  1  new york  3  0.5833333
# 11 1 4 bangalore  4  new york  3  0.5694444
# 12 3 5 bengaluru  1   newyork  1  0.4761905
# 13 3 4 bengaluru  1  new york  3  0.4583333
# 14 1 6 bangalore  4     nyork  1  0.4370370
# 15 3 6 bengaluru  1     nyork  1  0.4370370
```

You could try different methods in `stringsim`. Jaro-Winkler has the advantage that it is relatively fast for large data sets.

Phonetic coders are sometimes too rough (quiet different strings can have the same phonetic encoding; especially soundex) and are usually developed specific for (American) last names.

Answer (score 4):

The `phonics` library, which has soundex capabilities, might be helpful here.  Assuming that `Bangalore` is the correct spelling, you could compare other city names, possibly misspelled, against this reference:

```
library(phonics)
x <- 'Bangalore'
y <- 'Banglore'

if (soundex(x) == soundex(y) & x != y) {
    # handle misspelling for Bangalore
}
```

The above logic just says that if `Bangalore` and `Banglore` sound the same, but yet are spelled differently, then flag the pair for inspection.

Comment: Just to add, there's a whole bunch of phonetic coders in the `phonics` package - including `nysiis()` and friends, which might work well.